# Unable to install rjb on mac, no header directory in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers

Tags: java, rjb

When I install rjb on mac, there is some error, as follows:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rjb:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /Users/twer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby extconf.rb


extconf.rb failed
```

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:

```
--with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/twer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby
extconf.rb:45:in `open': No such file or directory - /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers (Errno::ENOENT)
    from extconf.rb:45
```

Gem files will remain installed in `/Users/twer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@home-ideas/gems/rjb-1.3.3` for inspection.
Results logged to `/Users/twer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@home-ideas/gems/rjb-1.3.3/ext/gem_make.out`

Then I try to install Java developer package to solve the problem. But there is still `no/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers directory`.
 Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed rjb, but I'm on 1.9.3-p327... Perhaps `rvm install 1.9.3-p327` and see how you get on?

Comment: Thank you. I install jdk again and there is /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers now. But I don't know why still can't find jni.h. I can find it in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers, but when I install rjb, it still can't find. I don't know why....

Comment: ERROR:  Error installing rjb:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
        /Users/twer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for jni.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
....
extconf.rb:67:in `create_rjb_makefile': no jni.h in -I$(topdir) -I$(hdrdir) -I$(srcdir) -I"/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/include" -I"/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers" (RuntimeError)

Comment: Where's your jni.h file located? Did you try rvm use jruby?